# load earlier messages concept in tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

[image]

I was trying to add the load earlier messages concept same as Whats app. But it is inserting the rows from the bottom of the table instead of the top.

```
 #define kNumberOfItemsToAdd 20

-(IBAction)loadearliermessages:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger i, totalNumberOfItems = [messageArray count];
    newNumberOfItemsToDisplay = MIN(totalNumberOfItems, numberOfItemsToDisplay + kNumberOfItemsToAdd);
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (i=numberOfItemsToDisplay; i<newNumberOfItemsToDisplay; i++) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
    numberOfItemsToDisplay = newNumberOfItemsToDisplay;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Anybody has idea that how to load content from top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your index paths so that they range from zero to `newNumberOfItems-numberOfItemsToDisplay`.

You'll also need to fetch the right elements in your data source so that the items in the new range are indeed the older messages.

Comment: Do you have any sample code? Actuallu I am unable to manage index paths

Comment: `for (i=0; i<newNumberOfItemsToDisplay-numberOfItemsToDisplay; i++) { [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];}`

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot. Please check it. You can see that test 7 appears at the top of the tableview but according to my requirement the recent messages must be at the bottom of the tableview.